# Selecting records timestamped in a certain time range of each other

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you go about selecting records timestamped within a certain amount of time of each other?

Application and sought solution:

I have a table with records of clicks, I am wanting to go through and find the clicks from the same IP that occurred within a certain time period.

e.g.: SELECT ALL ip_address WHERE 5 or more of the same ip_address, occurred/are grouped within/timestamped, within 10 minutes of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided not to try for a single query on the raw data.

After discussion with a friend, and then reading about options mentioning the memory engine, and PHP memcatche; I decided to go with a regular table to record click counts that use a time to live timestamp. After that timestamp is passed, a new ttl is assigned and the count is re-set.
One thing is for my application I can't be exactly sure how long the parameter configuration settings will be - if they are larger and the memory gets cleared, then things start over.

It isn't a perfect solution if it is run on user link click, but it should be pretty good about catching click fraud storms, and do the job.

Some managing PHP/MySQL code ("Drupalized queries"):

```
$timeLimit = $clickQualityConfigs['edit-submitted-within-x-num-of-same-ip-clicks']." ".$clickQualityConfigs['edit-submitted-time-period-same-ip-ban']; // => 1 days // e.g.
$filterEndTime = strtotime("+".$timeLimit);

$timeLimitUpdate_results = db_query('UPDATE {ip_address_count} 
SET ttl_time_stamp = :filterendtime, click_count = :clickcountfirst WHERE ttl_time_stamp < :timenow', array(':filterendtime' => $filterEndTime, ':clickcountfirst' => '0', ':timenow' => time()));

$clickCountUpdate_results = db_query('INSERT INTO {ip_address_count} (ip_address,ttl_time_stamp,click_count) 
VALUES (:ipaddress,:timestamp,:clickcountfirst) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE click_count = click_count + 1', array(':ipaddress' => $ip_address,':timestamp' => $filterEndTime,':clickcountfirst' => '1'));
```

---

DB info:

```
CREATE TABLE `ip_address_count` (
   `ip_address` varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `ttl_time_stamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `click_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ip_address`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select record like that

```
$recorddate = date("Y-m-d");
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$recorddate');
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP function converts date to timestamp. And you can easily use it in your queries.

If you want to grab the record in 10 minutes interval you can do something like that

```
$starttime = "2012-08-30 19:00:00";
$endtime   = "2012-08-30 19:10:00";
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$starttime') AND date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$endtime') ;
```

Comment: But what if the 10 records he wants are at the start of the range?

Comment: @X-Zero jmhead can limit query and he can user order by. I think this answer is enough.

Comment: +1 - your second answer is closer to what I was thinking of, although usually ranges are supposed to be lower-bound inclusive - `>=` (and upper-bound exclusive like you've done here).  Thankfully, you've avoided the use of `BETWEEN` (especially given the use of timestamps...)

Comment: HM, not sure that this would fit the bill, because to get the dates you first have to do a query or a series of queries to grab the start and end times.  

I won't know up front what the times are, I'd just like to be able to SELECT all WHERE the dates are x time period close together, regardless of the time window.
Specifically what I am doing is I have a table for link clicks, and I want to know how many were from the same IP address within a certain time period.

It seems I might have to do multiple queries to get the info I want.

Comment: @jmhead if you edit your topic and tell what you want exactly we can help you. We can do with a single query. But first of all we understand you exactly.